# Operator && cannot be applied to operands of type double and bool

Tags: c#

I have problem with sum operator.

```
var  Total_money = List.Sum(x => x.Cost && x.Type_of_room == Type);
```

So I got the message "Operator && cannot be applied to operands of type double and bool"

Comment: Have you read docs?

Comment: What exactly do you expect `x.Cost && x.Type_of_room == Type` to mean?

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message?  It is quite explicit in what the problem is.

Comment: Cost is double so your condition is if(double) which wont work

Comment: `x.Cost` has nothing to compare, this is possible if the data type is bool, but I see in your case that it looks like it is an int

Comment: @JavaHead1560: That's... even more random than what the OP originally tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely need to filter first then sum the cost

```
var  Total_money = List.Where(x => x.Type_of_room == Type).Sum(x => x.Cost);
```

Comment: It's work now. So the reason for that is make the list with condition first and then sum information in this list. Is it correct?
So why count could use with many condition inside and no need to filter out the list first but still work? For ex: var Room = List.Count(x => x.Type_of_room == Type && x.Date_rent.Date = '15")

Comment: Sum is taking an aggregation expression while count it taking a predicate expression. Same as where

Answer (score 1):

Your expression `x.Cost` returns a double, `x.Type_of_room == Type` returns a bool.  These both cannot be compared with `&&`.

So you might make the cost thing a bool expression like `x.Cost > 0`, if you want to have those with costs, for example.

If you want to have the costs summed up from those whose `x.Type_of_room == Type`, you should split the expression to a `.Where(x => x.Type_of_room == Type)` followed by a `.Sum(x => x.Cost)` which results in:

```
var totalMoney = List
                  .Where(x => x.Type_of_room == Type)
                  .Sum(x => x.Cost);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Func within Sum() is supposed to return a number, yet you are treating it as a boolean expression as if it where supposed to return true or false.

One way to overcome this is to filter your query first with the query syntax and then take the sum of the values using the method syntax.

```
var  Total_money = (from x in List where x.Type_of_room == Type select x.Cost).Sum();
```